# Retrieve The Second Name Using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want to use Regex to retrieve the person and its address.

The result wild be :
All Frank Anderson and its address inside of a string list.

Problem:
The problem I'm facing is that I cannot retrieve the second name that is "Frank Andre Anderson" based on my regex.

It also might be other people who can have another second name.

Thank you!

```
string pFirstname = "Frank"
string pLastname = "Anderson";

string input = w.DownloadString("http://www.birthday.no/sok/?f=Frank&l=Anderson");

Match theRegex8 = Regex.Match(input, @"(?<=\><b>)" + pFirstname + "(.+?)" + pLastname + "</b></a></h3><p><span>(.+?<)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

foreach (var matchgroup in theRegex8.Groups)
{
    var sss = matchgroup;
}
```

The current result that I'm using the code is:
[image: enter image description dd]

Comment: If this question is about regex, clear all the fog. Remove the downloadstring part, and generaly read [ask] and create an MCVE

Comment: Can you post a sample `input`?

Comment: Claudio - inform me if you need anything more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be looking for something like

```
(?<=>[^<]*<b>)Frank([^<]+)Anderson</b></a></h3><p><span>([^<]+)
```

See [concise RegexStorm demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%3E%5B%5E%3C%5D*%3Cb%3E)Frank(%5B%5E%3C%5D%2B)Anderson%3C%2Fb%3E%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fh3%3E%3Cp%3E%3Cspan%3E(%5B%5E%3C%5D%2B)&i=a%20href%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.birthday.se%2Fsok%2F%3Ff%3DFrank%26l%3DAnderson%22%3Eklikk%20her%20%3Cu%3E%26raquo%3B%3C%2Fu%3E%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22birthdaylist%22%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Ch3%3E%3Cb%3E1.%3C%2Fb%3E%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%2Fperson%2F10%2F11%2Ffrank_alexander%2Fanderson%2Fbrumunddal%2F%22%3E%3Cb%3EFrank%20Alexander%20Anderson%3C%2Fb%3E%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fh3%3E%3Cp%3E%3Cspan%3EPellevika%2C%202380%20Brumunddal%20%26nbsp%3B%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%2Fperson%2F10%2F11%2Ffrank_alexander%2Fanderson%2Fbrumunddal%2F%22%3ETele%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fspan%3EFy)

In C#, the regex declaration will be

```
Match theRegex8 = Regex.Match(input, @"(?<=>[^<]*<b>)" + pFirstname + "([^<]+)" + pLastname + "</b></a></h3><p><span>([^<]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The problem you had was with `.` matching any character while we need to restrict to a non-angle bracket.

## Update

Perhaps, you could leverage `HtmlAgilityPack` by getting all `<a>` tags that have `<b>` as the first child, and then get the `InnerText` that meets your conditions:

```
var conditions = new[] { pFirstname, pLastname};
var seconds = new List<string>();
var webGet = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
var doc = webGet.Load("http://www.birthday.no/sok/?f=Frank&l=Anderson");
var a_nodes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a").Where(a => a.HasChildNodes && a.ChildNodes[0].Name == "b");
var res = a_nodes.Select(a => a.ChildNodes[0].InnerText).Where(b => conditions.All(condition => b.Contains(condition))).ToList();
foreach (var name in res)
{
    var splts = name.Split(new[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (splts.GetLength(0) > 2) // we have 3 elements at the least
       seconds.Add(name.Trim().Substring(name.Trim().IndexOf(" ") + 1, name.Trim().LastIndexOf(" ") - name.Trim().IndexOf(" ") - 1));
}
```

This way, you will get just the second names. I could not test this code, but I think you get the gist.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you, please also consider upvoting if the answer turned out helpful to you.